# How to change a color to random in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I've tried countless times to try and get this to work. I've moved loads of it around but still, nothing works. When I press the M key, my lights are meant to change to random colours. However, they change just to white.

This is what i have...

float colorArray[100][3];   // Create an array for random colors

**keyPressed function:**

```
    case 'm' | 'M':
        updateLights(2);
    break;
```

**defined_to_openGL function:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(colorArray[i][0],colorArray[i][1],colorArray[i][2]);
        glTranslatef(-50*i/2,-20,0.5); // Begin the first circle at -50, -20. Then multiply by i to create a space between them.
        drawLights(2.0f);
    glPopMatrix();

    if(i <= 3)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(colorArray[i][0],colorArray[i][1],colorArray[i][2]);
            glTranslatef(-38,-20,0.5);
            drawLights(2.0f);
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(colorArray[i][0],colorArray[i][1],colorArray[i][2]);
            glTranslatef(-12,-20,0.5);
            drawLights(2.0f);
        glPopMatrix();
    }

}
```

**Update lights function:**

```
{
    cout << "update lights" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        colorArray[i][0] = rand() % 255;
        colorArray[i][1] = rand() % 255;
        colorArray[i][2] = rand() % 255;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `glColor3f` which accepts 3 float parameters in `[0.0,1.0]` for each color intensity while `rand()%255` produces an output which is in `[0,254]`.

You can either switch to `glColor3ub( GLubyte red, GLubyte green, GLubyte blue)` which accepts an unsigned byte (and change modulo to `%256` since you are skipping a value with `255`) or generate a value in `[0.0,1.0]`by changing your random generation to 
`rand()/((float)RAND_MAX+1)`
but this mean that you will have to change the type of `colorArray` to `GLFloat`.

Comment: Dude...I'm actually in love with you now. Thank you ever so much! glColor3f was screwing me over! ¬_¬

Comment: Mind that the whole opengl library offers different way to call the same method with different input type, this is true for many functions.

Comment: @Jack: Please don't call OpenGL a library, because it isn't. It's an API specification, which can be implemented as a library. Yes I know that the 'L' originally stands for library, but I personally backronymed it to *layer*.